# List and Separate directores in c#

Tags: c#, list, directory

With *Directory.GetDirectories* I can list all folders,but I need to separate the sub folders from a determinate point, for example, I have this list

- folderA/
- folderB/
- folderA/subFolderA/
- folderB/subFolderB/
- folderA/subFolderA/SubFolderB
- folderB/subFolderB/SubFolderB

But I need to separate each path, folderA to folderB

- folderA/
- folderA/subFolderA/
- folderA/subFolderA/SubFolderB

And
 - folderB/ 
 - folderB/subFolderB/
 - folderB/subFolderB/SubFolderB

It's possible?

Comment: what you  have tried so far

Comment: What do you mean with _separate_? GetDirectories already returns every single entry as a separate string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Search options to give you the top level directories then process each one in turn to get its subdirectories

```
Directory.GetDirectories(thePath, aSearchPattern ,SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to seperate the directories returned by EnumerateDirectories  in two list depending on how the string starts with

```
List<String> foldersA = new List<string>();
List<String> foldersB = new List<string>();
List<String> otherFolders = new List<string>();  // Eventually 

string rootPath = @"D:\temp";
foreach(string s in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(rootPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    // remove the rootPath part to apply the StartsWith check
    string temp = s.Substring(rootPath.Length + 1);

    if(s.StartsWith("folderA"))
       foldersA.Add(temp);
    else if(s.StartsWith("folderB"))
       foldersB.Add(temp);
    else
       otherFolders.Add(temp);
}
```

**From MSDN**

> The EnumerateDirectories and GetDirectories methods differ as follows:
>   When you use EnumerateDirectories, you can start enumerating the
>   collection of names before the whole collection is returned; when you
>   use GetDirectories, you must wait for the whole array of names to be
>   returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are
>   working with many files and directories, EnumerateDirectories can be
>   more efficient.